# Orthonormal basis for the null space of almost-Householder matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

A matrix $H$ is defined as:
$$H = I - vv^T$$
where $v$ is a unit vector.

- What is the rank of $H$?
- What would be an orthonormal basis for the null space of $H$?
- How do we find the number of zero eigenvalues and their
  associated eigenvector?

Comment: This is not a Householder matrix. A Householder matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: @Victor Liu: True! yes thanks, it is not really a Householder matrix.

Comment: @Victor Liu: How did you determine that $H$ is singular?

Comment: @haver : $Hv = v - \langle v,v \rangle v = v-v = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $H$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=|\lambda I-H|=(\lambda-1)^n+Tr(vv^T)(\lambda-1)^{n-1}
$$
for $vv^T$ is a Rank-$1$ matrix and all principal minors above $2$ are $0$.

Let $v=\pmatrix{v_1\\\vdots\\v_n}$. Then 
$$
vv^T=\pmatrix{v_1v_1\cdots v_1v_n\\ \vdots \hspace{15 mm} \vdots \\ v_nv_1 \cdots v_nv_n}
$$
So 
$$Tr(vv^T)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nv_k^2=1$$
And we have
$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)^{n-1}
$$
So there are $n-1$ eigenvalue of $1$ and $1$ eigenvalue of $0$. And 
$$\text{Rank}(H)=n-1$$

Since $Hv=v-vv^Tv=v-v=0$, $v$ is the only eigenvector for $0$, and the only orthonormal basis vector for the null space of $H$.

Comment: Yes. It makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Pick any vector $w \in V$ where $V$ is an inner product space of dimension $n$ ; assume the basis has been chosen so that $v^{\top} w = \langle w,v \rangle$. Then 
$$
Hw = w - v v^{\top} w = w - \langle w,v \rangle v. 
$$
It follows that if $v$ has norm $1$, $H$ is the orthogonal projection operator to the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$ orthogonal to $v$ ; call it $W$. Its eigenvalues are therefore $0$ and $1$, where $1$ has (geometric) multiplicity $n-1$ and $0$ has multiplicity $1$. An orthogonal basis for $W$ together with $v$ gives an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors for $H$. In particular, the rank of $H$ is $n-1$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I understand your explanation up to: " its eigenvalues are therefore 0 and 1" the following parts are not very clear to me. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on them.

Comment: @haver : Since $Hv = v - \langle  v,v \rangle v = v - v = 0$, $v$ lies in the kernel and has eigenvalue $0$. Any vector $w$ orthogonal to $v$ satisfies $Hw = w$, so it is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. Therefore if we take an orthonormal basis for the subspace of vectors orthogonal to $v$, say $\{w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1}\}$, then $\{w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1},v \}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$ and over this basis, the matrix for $H$ looks like 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &  & &  \\
0 & 1 & \ddots &  &  \\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
 & &  \ddots & 1 & 0 \\
 & &  & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Great! I see it much better now. Just more clarification about the (n-1) w and the one v in the basis .. and the capital $V$?  :) I am almost there

Comment: @hayer : I am afraid there is not much more I can detail. Just try thinking about it for a little while, or maybe ask a more precise question?

Comment: I get it all now. However, what would be the associated eigenvector to $v$ that satisfies $Hv = 0$? How to state it formally?

Comment: @hayer : Um, I think you meant eigenvalue. If $Hv = 0 = 0v$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! thanks .. Although your explanation was clearer and simpler, I'll have to mark math craze answer as correct, as he provided a correct answer to the orthonormal basis vector for the null space, which is $v$.

Comment: @heyer : I diagonalized the whole matrix! If you wanted the basis of the null space you just had to look at the eigenvalues corresponding to each vector.